# Mongodb Aggregation slow count using facet

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am wanting to use a facet to create a simple query that i can use to get paged data, however i have noticed that if i do this i get really poor performance when compared to running just two seperate queries.

As a quick test i created a collection with 50000 random documents and ran the following test.

```
var x = new Date();
var a = {
count : db.getCollection("test").find({}).count(),
data: db.getCollection("test").find({}).skip(0).limit(10)
};

var y = new Date();
print('result ' + a);
print(y - x);

var x = new Date();
var a = db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {

            }
        }, 
        {
         "$facet" : {
        "data": [
          {
            "$skip": 0
          },
          {
            "$limit": 10
          }
        ],
        "pageInfo": [
          {
            "$group": {
              "_id": null,
              "count": {
                "$sum": 1
              }
            }
          }
        ]       

         }
        }
    ]
)
var y = new Date();
print('result ' + a);
print(y - x);
```

The result of this is that two seperate queries one for find the other for count takes around **2 milliseconds** vs the aggregation single query taking upwards of **500 milliseconds**.

Why is it that the aggregation is so slow?

**Update**

Even just a count without a facet within an aggregation is slow

```
var x = new Date();
var a = db.getCollection("test").find({}).count();
var y = new Date();
print('result ' + a);
print(y - x);

var x = new Date();
var a = db.getCollection("test").aggregate(
    [
        { "$count" : "count" }
    ]
)
var y = new Date();
print('result ' + a);
print(y - x);
```

In the above with my test data set, the aggregation count takes **200ms** vs the Count method taking **2ms**.

This issue extends into the NodeJs Mongodb Driver where the .Count() method has been deprecated and replaced with a countDocuments() method, under the hood the new countDocuments() method is using an aggregation and not the count method on a find just like my example above it has significantly worse performance to the point at which i will continue using the deprecated method over the newer countDocuments() method.

Comment: Remove the first `$match` stage and use `$count` query instead of `$group`... `.aggregate([
  { "$facet" : {
  "data": [
    {
      "$skip": 0
    },
    {
      "$limit": 10
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": [
    {
      $count:"count"
    }
  ]       
  }}
])`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it is specifically formatted like that because i have a complicated $match this is a simplified example showing the issue. Which is that counts in aggregations are slow.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is slow. The `count()` method just returns the cursor size after a query is *applied* (which does not necessarily require all documents to be read, depending on your query and indices). Furthermore, with an empty query, the query optimizer knows that all documents ought to be returned and basically only has to return `length(_id_1)`.

Aggregations, by definition, do not work that way. Unless there is a match stage actually ruling out a document, each and every document *is read from “disk”* (MongoDB’s own cache and FS caches aside for the moment) for further processing.

Comment: If this is the case, why is the NodeJS driver depreciating the .Count() method in favor of using one that relies on the aggregation under the hood, it is going to kill performance everywhere.

Comment: @Daxxy Maybe because [of the bug SERVER-3645](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3645)? This humble commenter found out that you can get the correct results using an aggregation. However, this bug was fixed in 3.7.4... Maybe because of 3.4 and 3.6 support? Further reading suggested: [Aggregation Pipeline Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-behavior) and **[`db.collection.count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db.collection.count)**

Comment: @Markus do you know if there's official documentation about this? I'm basically running into the same thing and was searching for documentation that explains it but haven't found anything.

Comment: @alexvy86 Actually, the documentation of count in the comment above explains its behaviour. As for the aggregation:The description of [early filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#early-filtering) describes that if, and only if, there is a `$match` stage at the beginning of a pipeline, a subset is accessed. Which by implication means that if you do not limit the pipeline to a subset of the collection, all documents in the collection are accessed.

Comment: Ah, found it under the [Index use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#index-use) section, you're right:
> If, however, the query can use an index but the query predicates do not access a single contiguous range of index keys or the query also contains conditions on fields outside the index, then in addition to using the index, MongoDB must also read the documents to return the count.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue, and I just hope that anyone might have a better answer then what was previously posted.

I have a "user" collection with 12 million users in it, using MongoDB 5.0.

My query looks like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { '$sort': { updated_at: -1 } },
  { '$facet': { 
      results: [      
          { $skip: 0 },
          { $limit: 20 }
      ], 
      total: [
          { $count: 'count' }
      ] 
    } 
  }
])
```

The query takes around 1 minute, so that is not acceptable.

I have an index on "updated_at", that is not the issue.

Also, I have this issue even if I run it directly on MongoShell in Compass. So it is not related to any NodeJs Mongo Driver as was previously suspected.

Can I somehow tell Mongo to use the estimated count here?
Or is there any other way to improve the query?

Comment: did you ever find a way to improve the query?

Comment: do not use $facet at all. After facing same problem switched to the two independent queries - one for page results, second for total

Comment: @AbeCaymo no, unfortunately not. My understanding is that indexes are not used in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I too had problem with $facet and using $count, I finally managed to find $unionWith which can be used as such:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "postId": "e5ca94f0-c73f-11ee-9406-114961a223d4",
            "parentId": null,
            "status": "approved"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 5
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
           ....random...
        }
    },
    {
        "$unionWith": {
            "coll": "CommunityPostComment2",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "postId": "e5ca94f0-c73f-11ee-9406-114961a223d4",
                        "parentId": null,
                        "status": "approved"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$count": "postId"
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "count": "$postId"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

This gives you a new record in your array as a last item, so

```
const {count} = yourArray.pop();
```

From 52ms to 0ms!